# Why is my partitioning date column empty?

Tags: dataiku

I am currently trying to use the concept of partitioning for one of my datasets, the idea being to be able to enrich it with a temporal dimension which is not present in the database.

I have well defined my file hierarchy and my pattern to find my partitions

[image]

I try to add a column to my dataset containing the date of the partition

[image]

But the problem is that once the recipe is launched, my output column is empty for some reason...

[image]

If anyone has an idea of what I'm missing, I'd love to hear it

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This isn't really related to the <sql> _language_.)

Comment: I'm currently using none as every operations is done on Dataiku with Spark engine